# Kotlin channel.receive() does not timeout when used in withTimeout() block

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want `channel.receive()` to timeout to do some other stuff when the channel does not receive a message after a specific time.

I have tried using a withTimeout() block but it actually does not timeout.

```
val incomingNotification = withTimeout(1000L) {
    (session.outgoing as Channel<Frame>).receive()
}
```

Could it be that `receive()` is actually not cancelable?
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Which dispatcher is the coroutine running on?

Comment: A dispatcher could be busy with another task to resume the execution on timeout

Comment: It's running in its own coroutine in a runBlocking block used for a JUnit test.

Comment: Yeah @EugenePetrenko you are right. The dispatcher has been busy because i was using another runBlocking on the same thread somewhere else. Now its fixed. Thank you.

Comment: How's have you fixed it exactly? I've the same problem.

Comment: I actually can't remember the exact solution, but according to the previous comments there must have bin another  runBlocking or similar somewhere else and i just removed/replaced it with something non blocking.